# Transform data from Snoflake table to CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-transform

I have data stored in a Snowflake table like the example below:
[image]

And now I wanted to create a CSV file in an S3 bucket using a Snowflake task.
This csv file should have the following format:
[image]

This is, the logic is (more or less) to transpose the table, having always a number of fixed columns (Company, Financial-L1, Financial-L2, Financial-L3, HR-L1, HR-L2) and in the case we do not have data for a given level then we use the member_id from the previous level (e.g. for C2 we do not have FINANCIAL-L2 or L3, so we picked the value from the FINANCIAL-L1).

**V2:**

Now I do not have EVAL_DESC, but I know that we have always 4 sub-levels inside each business unit and that the order the records appears are from top level hierarchy to down level hierarchy. And in the case we do not have records for all the 4 sub-levels of a depart we should use the member_id from the previous top level.

[image]

CSV Outpu:
[image]

How can I achieve this in the data transformation side?

Answer (score 1):

You can do transpose in snowflake as below; however as per your data-set it might include NULLs -

```
snowflake1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select * from (select company,concat(BU,'-',EVAL_DESC) as col1,member_id from TEST
                                     _PIVOT) tab1 pivot(min(member_id) for col1 in ('FINANCIAL-L1','FINANCIAL-L2','FINA
                                     NCIAL-L3','HR-L1','HR-L2','HR-L3','BUSINESS-L1','BUSINESS-L2','BUSINESS-L3')) as P
                                      ORDER BY company;
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| COMPANY | 'FINANCIAL-L1' | 'FINANCIAL-L2' | 'FINANCIAL-L3' | 'HR-L1' | 'HR-L2' | 'HR-L3' | 'BUSINESS-L1' | 'BUSINESS-L2' | 'BUSINESS-L3' |
|---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------|
| C1      | ID1            | ID2            | ID3            | ID4     | ID5     | NULL    | NULL          | NULL          | NULL          |
| C2      | ID6            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | ID7           | NULL          | NULL          |
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
2 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.307s
```

For treatment of NULLs you can adopt an apprach as below where in you specify columns names in select clause and use ifnull function -
I have just selected a sub-set of columns, but same can be expanded to get entire data-set, you just need to put all column names manually

```
snowflake1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select company as comp, "'FINANCIAL-L2'" as f2 from (select company,concat(BU,'-',
                                     EVAL_DESC) as col1,member_id from TEST_PIVOT) tab1 pivot(min(member_id) for col1 i
                                     n ('FINANCIAL-L1','FINANCIAL-L2','FINANCIAL-L3','HR-L1','HR-L2','HR-L3','BUSINESS-
                                     L1','BUSINESS-L2','BUSINESS-L3')) as P ORDER BY company;
+------+------+
| COMP | F2   |
|------+------|
| C1   | ID2  |
| C2   | NULL |
+------+------+
2 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.334s
```

This is the final result set with transpose and no NULLs -

```
snowflake1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select company as comp, ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L2'","'FINANCIAL-L1'") as f2 from (sele
                                     ct company,concat(BU,'-',EVAL_DESC) as col1,member_id from TEST_PIVOT) tab1 pivot(
                                     min(member_id) for col1 in ('FINANCIAL-L1','FINANCIAL-L2','FINANCIAL-L3','HR-L1','
                                     HR-L2','HR-L3','BUSINESS-L1','BUSINESS-L2','BUSINESS-L3')) as P ORDER BY company;
+------+-----+
| COMP | F2  |
|------+-----|
| C1   | ID2 |
| C2   | ID6 |
+------+-----+
2 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.313s
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.
Now imagine that I do not had the "Eval_Desc" and that I would have to fill sub levels (Always 4 by each business unit). How could I manage this? For more details, please check V2 in the description!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. You see NULLs as there is no FINANCIAL, HR BU for C2, no BUSINESS BU for C1

```
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select * from test_pivot_1;
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| COMPANY | BU        | MEMBER_ID |
|---------+-----------+-----------|
| C1      | FINANCIAL | ID1       |
| C1      | FINANCIAL | ID2       |
| C1      | FINANCIAL | ID3       |
| C1      | HR        | ID4       |
| C1      | HR        | ID5       |
| C2      | FINANCIAL | ID6       |
| C2      | BUSINESS  | ID7       |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
7 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.148s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>select company as comp,
                                     ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L1'","'FINANCIAL-L2'") as "FINANCIAL-L1",
                                     ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L2'","'FINANCIAL-L1'") as "FINANCIAL-L2",
                                     ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L3'","'FINANCIAL-L1'") as "FINANCIAL-L2",
                                     ifnull("'HR-L1'","'HR-L2'") as "HR-L1",
                                     ifnull("'HR-L2'","'HR-L1'") as "HR-L2",
                                     ifnull("'HR-L3'","'HR-L1'") as "HR-L3",
                                     ifnull("'BUSINESS-L1'","'BUSINESS-L2'") as "BUSINESS-L1",
                                     ifnull("'BUSINESS-L2'","'BUSINESS-L1'") as "BUSINESS-L2",
                                     ifnull("'BUSINESS-L3'","'BUSINESS-L1'") as "BUSINESS-L3"
                                     from
                                     (select company,member_id,BU||'-'||'L'||row_number() over (partition by bu order b
                                     y bu) as bu from TEST_PIVOT_1) tab1
                                     pivot(min(member_id)
                                     for BU
                                     in ('FINANCIAL-L1','FINANCIAL-L2','FINANCIAL-L3','HR-L1','HR-L2','HR-L3','BUSINESS
                                     -L1','BUSINESS-L2','BUSINESS-L3')) as P
                                     ORDER BY company;
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| COMP | FINANCIAL-L1 | FINANCIAL-L2 | FINANCIAL-L2 | HR-L1 | HR-L2 | HR-L3 | BUSINESS-L1 | BUSINESS-L2 | BUSINESS-L3 |
|------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------|
| C1   | ID1          | ID2          | ID3          | ID4   | ID5   | ID4   | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        |
| C2   | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | ID7         | ID7         | ID7         |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
2 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.166s
SNOWFLAKE1#COMPUTE_WH@TEST_DB.PUBLIC>
```

Comment: There is only one issue, which is:
In the new version I have always 4 sub-levels inside each business unit and sometimes I do not have data for 4 sub-levels for a given businss unit, meaning that the column name cannot be generated with the row_number().
Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this is an acceptable answer-

```
select company as comp,
ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L1'","'FINANCIAL-L2'") as "FINANCIAL-L1",
ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L2'","'FINANCIAL-L1'") as "FINANCIAL-L2",
ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L3'","'FINANCIAL-L1'") as "FINANCIAL-L3",
ifnull("'FINANCIAL-L4'","'FINANCIAL-L1'") as "FINANCIAL-L4",
ifnull("'HR-L1'","'HR-L2'") as "HR-L1",
ifnull("'HR-L2'","'HR-L1'") as "HR-L2",
ifnull("'HR-L3'","'HR-L1'") as "HR-L3",
ifnull("'HR-L4'","'HR-L1'") as "HR-L4",
ifnull("'BUSINESS-L1'","'BUSINESS-L2'") as "BUSINESS-L1",
ifnull("'BUSINESS-L2'","'BUSINESS-L1'") as "BUSINESS-L2",
ifnull("'BUSINESS-L3'","'BUSINESS-L1'") as "BUSINESS-L3",
ifnull("'BUSINESS-L4'","'BUSINESS-L1'") as "BUSINESS-L4"
from
(select company,member_id,t2.lbu as lbu from TEST_PIVOT_1 tp, 
(select distinct bu,bu||'-'||t1.col as lbu from test_pivot_1,(select 'L1' as l1,'L2' as l2,'L3' as l3,'L4' as l4) t1 unpivot (col1 for col in (l1,l2,l3,l4)) ) t2 
where tp.bu=t2.bu) tab1
pivot(min(member_id)
for lbu in ('FINANCIAL-L1','FINANCIAL-L2','FINANCIAL-L3','FINANCIAL-L4','HR-L1','HR-L2','HR-L3','HR-L4','BUSINESS-L1','BUSINESS-L2','BUSINESS-L3','BUSINESS-L4')) as P
ORDER BY company;

+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| COMP | FINANCIAL-L1 | FINANCIAL-L2 | FINANCIAL-L3 | FINANCIAL-L4 | HR-L1 | HR-L2 | HR-L3 | HR-L4 | BUSINESS-L1 | BUSINESS-L2 | BUSINESS-L3 | BUSINESS-L4 |
|------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------|
| C1   | ID1          | ID1          | ID1          | ID1          | ID4   | ID4   | ID4   | ID4   | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        |
| C2   | ID6          | ID6          | ID6          | ID6          | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | ID7         | ID7         | ID7         | ID7         |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```